# Is this use of Parallel.ForEach() thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, thread-safety, parallel.foreach

Essentially, I am working with this:

```
var data = input.AsParallel();
List<String> output = new List<String>();

Parallel.ForEach<String>(data, line => {
    String outputLine = ""; 
    // ** Do something with "line" and store result in "outputLine" **

    // Additionally, there are some this.Invoke statements for updating UI

    output.Add(outputLine);
});
```

Input is a `List<String>` object. The `ForEach()` statement does some processing on each value, updates the UI, and adds the result to the `output` `List`. Is there anything inherently wrong with this?

**Notes:**

- Output order is **unimportant**

**Update:**

Based on feedback I've gotten, I've added a manual `lock` to the `output.Add` statement, as well as to the UI updating code.

Comment: What is your definition of Thread safe? does order in output matters? it would help if you give all of the surrounding code.

Comment: @Sanjeevakumar Hiremath: Sorry, I should have included those details.

Comment: I edited my answer to show a way that doesn't involve `lock` etc

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes; `List<T>` is not thread safe, so adding to it ad-hoc from arbitrary threads (quite possibly at the same time) is doomed. You should use a thread-safe list instead, or add locking manually. Or maybe there is a `Parallel.ToList`.

Also, if it matters: insertion order will not be guaranteed.

This version *is* safe, though:

```
var output = new string[data.Count];

Parallel.ForEach<String>(data, (line,state,index) =>
{
    String outputLine = index.ToString();
    // ** Do something with "line" and store result in "outputLine" **

    // Additionally, there are some this.Invoke statements for updating UI
    output[index] = outputLine;
});
```

here we are using `index` to update a different array index per parallel call.

Comment: Thank you! Luckily, in my case, output order is unimportant so I've just wrapped the add statement in a lock.

Comment: There is not a Parallel.ToList but there is ConcurrentQueue, or ConcurrentStack and others which were designed at the same time as the TPL.  They are thread safe and easy to use.  Since order does not matter they would work here.  And no locks!

Comment: There also is `.AsParallel()` and the ParallelEnumerable extension method `ToList()`

Comment: Beware that writing to an array in parallel, while thread-safe, is not necessarily fast. When multiple threads try to write to indices that reside in the same memory block, they wait for one another. I have not compared this to a thread-safe collection, however - it might certainly have the same limitation, since this is low-level stuff.

Answer (score 14):

> Is there anything inherently wrong with this?

Yes, everything. None of this is safe.  Lists are not safe for updating on multiple threads concurrently, and you can't update the UI from any thread other than the UI thread.

Comment: @SimpleCoder: You might find that you spend more time contending the lock than you gain in farming the work out to multiple cores. Is the work really expensive compared to the cost of adding it to a locked list? If not then you're probably making your program slower by doing it in parallel.  You might have better results with a collection designed for synchronization.

Comment: @SimpleCoder: And *adding locks* to the UI updates is *wrong*. The UI is *apartment threaded*, not *rental threaded*. The UI can only be called from one thread, the designated UI thread. Putting in locks and then calling it from the wrong thread is still illegal. If you want to update the UI from a worker thread then the worker thread must signal the UI thread that the UI thread needs to do the work.

Comment: @SimpleCoder - a `lock` is not sufficient for the UI; you need to use your local "do this on the UI" code; `Control.Invoke` for winforms, or `Dispatcher.Invoke` in WPF

Comment: I'm sorry if what I wrote was vague: I was always doing it like this: `Action updateProgressBar = () => { pbMain.Increment(1); }; lock(oLock) {this.Invoke(updateProgressBar); }`

Comment: @SimpleCoder - that `lock` is redundant; the message queue *is* thread safe (it kinda has to be, to work). So you can `Invoke` from everywhere at once. Adding a `lock` is a *potential* source of a deadlock, so I'd remove that one.

Comment: @SimpleCoder and it won't matter much, but IIRC there is special-case treatment given to `MethodInvoker` in this scenario, that avoids `DynamicInvoke`. Same signature, so *as a micro-optimisation* (i.e. almost certainly won't matter), you might want to use `MethodInvoker  updateProgressBar = ...`.

Comment: Look at the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace. I've used ConcurrentBag in place of List successfully many times.

Answer (score 5):

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) says the following about the thread safety of `List<T>`:

> Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
>
> A List(Of T) can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified. Enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. In the rare case where an enumeration contends with one or more write accesses, the only way to ensure thread safety is to lock the collection during the entire enumeration. To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization.

Thus, `output.Add(outputLine)` is *not* thread-safe and you need to ensure thread safety yourself, for example, by wrapping the add operation in a `lock` statement.

Answer (score 0):

When you want the results of a parallel operation, the [PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq) is more convenient than the [`Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel) class. You started well by converting your `input` to a [`ParallelQuery<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelquery-1):

```
ParallelQuery<string> data = input.AsParallel();
```

...but then you fed the `data` to the `Parallel.ForEach`, which treats it as a standard `IEnumerable<T>`. So the [`AsParallel()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asparallel) was wasted. It didn't provide any parallelization, only overhead. Here is the correct way to use PLINQ:

```
List<string> output = input
    .AsParallel()
    .Select(line =>
    {
        string outputLine = ""; 
        // ** Do something with "line" and store result in "outputLine" **
        return outputLine;
    })
    .ToList();
```

A few differences that you should have in mind:

1. The `Parallel` runs the code on the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) by default, but it's [configurable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.taskscheduler). The PLINQ uses exclusively the `ThreadPool`.
2. The `Parallel` by default has unlimited parallelism (it uses all the available threads of the `ThreadPool`). The PLINQ uses by default at most [`Environment.ProcessorCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.processorcount) threads.

Regarding the order of the results, PLINQ doesn't preserve the order by default. In case you want to preserve the order, you can attach the [`AsOrdered`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asordered) operator.