# Got "Index out of bounds" Error on List.Add() in c# Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, .net

Here is the code

```
List<string> something = new List<string>();
Parallel.ForEach(anotherList, r =>
     {
            .. do some work
             something.Add(somedata);
      });
```

I get the `Index out of bounds` error around 1 time per hundred run. Is there anyway to prevent the conflict (I assume) caused by threading?

Comment: Hint - Is `List<T>` thread safe for writing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605422/is-this-use-of-parallel-foreach-thread-safe

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In order to prevent the issue, instead of List you may use [`ConcurrentQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) or similar Concurrent collections in your parallel part. Once the parallel task is done, you can put it in the `List<T>`.

For more information take a look at System.Collections.Concurrent namespace to find the suitable collection for your use case.

Comment: Bingo, I am using `ConcurrentStack` now, it has `Push()` and `PushRange()`, very useful. Also a `ToList()` to finish

Answer (score 1):

I found that `lock (yourObject)` also negates the threading problem

Comment: You are basically negating the benefit of Parallel.Foreach method. I am sure using Concurrent object are much optimal solution that using lock object.