# Is it safe to r/w dictionary entries in a Parallel.ForEach in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, parallel.foreach, concurrentdictionary

I have a dictionary which I would like to modify it's values in a foreach loop, however, since my application is time critical, I'm trying to avoid all unnecessary locking overheads.

```
var loopData = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
var results = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

/// loopData and results are both initialized
/// with same set of keys.

Parallel.ForEach(loopData, data =>
    {
        var list = data.Value;
        /// manipulate list here

        /// Is this safe?
        results[data.Key] = list;
    });
```

Is the marked command safe to do? i.e., read/write to different key-value pairs of a dictionary without locking.

**Note 1:** I'm aware of concurrent collections namespace and all it's magnificent collections. Also I know that I can simply `lock` the highlighted command to ensure it's safety. As afore mentioned, my target is avoid *unnecessary* overheads as much as possible.

**Note 2:** a similar question is asked [at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605422/is-this-use-of-parallel-foreach-thread-safe). In that question the items of the container are modified inside the `Parallel.ForEach` loop. Whereas, here we are not modifying the key-value pairs, therefore the container is intact, only the data being pointed is changed. This makes it different from aforementioned question.

**Update**

1. This code works fine with no locking, but I *must* be sure.
2. Eventhough the `ConcurrentDictionary` would add least possible overhead, I would like to avoid it if this is safe.

Comment: What have you tried? What works and what does not work? Did you measure any performance issues when using ConcurrentDictionary? The add operation should be quite fast and not a problem if the "manipulate list" task takes a while

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605422/is-this-use-of-parallel-foreach-thread-safe

Comment: try adding 1000 rows to loopData and see if it still transfers to results correctly.

Comment: @MillieSmith yes I tried, and it works fine :) I might be lucky or that is simply how it is.

Comment: 50000 stops working on my machine.

Comment: Here is a very simplified version, I either get a exception thrown or the wrong count https://dotnetfiddle.net/SVSOVf I never get the right count. You must make adding safe some how.

Comment: @MillieSmith I checked your link, and I'm afraid I should disagree the _equality_ of the two scenarios, although they are very _similar_.

Comment: @Hamed, then would you mind explaining the difference and posting your example?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I think this is different from what I asked, in my question I'm not modifying the key's, I'm changing "the data pointed by the values" so neither the pointer is changed.

Comment: Have you tried using ConcurrentDictionary and found it to be too slow? It might be acceptable for your needs and you are trying to squeze out a immesurable amount of extra cycles.

Comment: @ThomasW. Please check _Note2_.

Comment: I think it's thread safe if you're modifying values for existing keys, but for the life of me I cannot find the page I read this on 30 minutes ago. I'd make it very clear in the code that this is happening though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is safe to read from the dictionary concurrently but it is not safe to write to it concurrently or read from it while writing concurrently. `ConcurrentDictionary` will be your fastest option for concurrent inserts.

Comment: I agree with you, and I was suspecting the safety that's why I asked the question. However, still I'm not convinced why it's not safe? Each value is a totally different item, independent from the rest, and the dictionary has only a pointer to that instance, so why should modifying one instance compromise the safety of other instance ?

Comment: @Hamed: the modification of the `list` variable is safe, but you asked for the `.Add()` operation. And that will give you errors like `"Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds."`

Comment: @Hamed because [internally dictionary is just a big `Entry[] entries;`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0) and it uses special logic to figure out where in the array to write or read. If you add more items than the size of `entries` it must re-size the array. If two threads attempt to write at the same time while one is resizing bad things happen.

Comment: This is also true for any other class in the `Collections` or `Collections.Generic` namespace. The collections in `Collections.Concurrent` have special logic that prevents two threads resizing the internal array at the same time so it is safe to read or write from them in the middle of an array resize.

Comment: @Hamed Please unaccept my answer, I would like to delete it now that you clarified that you are speaking of modifing existing indexes, not inserting new ones. I am not sure if it is thread safe or not.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain. Thanks for clarifications, I unaccepted your answer.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, I marked it back as an _answer_ because it's the best and shortest given answer :)

Answer (score 1):

From the comments I guess you have trouble understanding how many concurrent dictionaries you need. My annotations in code may help:

```
Parallel.ForEach(loopData, data =>
{
    var list = data.Value;       //<-- this is safe, because a read operation
    /// manipulate list here       <-- this is safe, because it operates on individual objects

    /// Is this safe?              <-- no, this is a write access
    results[data.Key] = list;
});
```

So you need only one concurrent dictionary, and that is for the `results` variable.