# Editing List items thread-safe?

Tags: c#, .net, list, thread-safety, parallel.foreach

Consider the following example:

```
public void Method(List<Item> items){
    List<Item> syncedSource = GetItems();

    Parallel.ForEach(items, item => {
        Item serverItem = syncedSource.Where(sourceItem => sourceItem.Name == item.Name).SingleOrDefault();
        if(serverItem != null){
            item.State = serverItem.State; // Thread-Safe?
        }
    });
}
```

Is `item.State = serverItem.State` thread-safe? As far as I understand it should be thread-safe because I'm not changing the List itself (add or remove) but rather an item.

Comment: It is thread safe in the sense that `Parallel.ForEach` will make sure same `item` is not grabbed by different threads. It is not thread safe in other senses.

Comment: So, in other words, if the ```Parallel.ForEach``` is the only one which is currently iterating over the list the ```item.State``` doesn't need an extra lock. If there was a second Loop iterating over the same collection simultaneously I had to implement a lock. (or if the item would be accessed from somewhere else at the same time)

Comment: this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605422/is-this-use-of-parallel-foreach-thread-safe

Comment: Maybe you should explain what you mean when you say, "thread safe." Are you asking whether there is anything _inherently_ wrong with performing that assignment inside the `Parallel.ForEach(...)` construct? Or are you asking about possible interactions with _other_ threads that might be running at the same time as the `ForEach`.  "Thread safe" is kind of a vague notion. building a program entirely out of supposedly "thread safe" operations does _not_ guarantee that the entire program will be free from thread-related issues.