# Employee details becoming null in C# Parallel.ForEach loop when fetching data from API

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have encountered an issue while fetching employee details from an API using a parallel foreach loop in C#. Please note I have used concurrentbag for the tasks to make it thread-safe and adding items to the list within the lock to avoid it being accessed by multiple threads at a time

Here's what I'm doing:

- I have a list of employee numbers.
- I iterate through this list using a parallel foreach loop.
- Inside the loop, I call an API with the current employee number to retrieve the employee details.
- I add the fetched employee details to a list.

However, I've noticed that sometimes the employee object in the employee details list becomes null. I'm unsure why this is happening and how to resolve it.

```
public List<ImportedEmployee> GetEmployees(List<String> empNumber)
{
    List<ImportedEmployee> employeeList = new List<ImportedEmployee>();

    try
    {
        List<ImportedEmployee> cb = new List<ImportedEmployee>();
        var tasks = new ConcurrentBag<Task>();

        Parallel.ForEach(empNumber, reference =>
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var importedEmployee = GetEmployeeDetails(reference.ToString());

                if (importedEmployee != null)
                {
                    lock (cb)
                    {
                        cb.Add(importedEmployee);
                    }
                }
            }));
        });

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.Where(t => t != null).ToArray());

        employeeList.AddRange(cb.ToList());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error("Error");
    }

    return employeeList;
}

public ImportedEmployee GetEmployeeDetails(string empNum)
{
    ImportedEmployee employeeDetails = new ImportedEmployee();

    try
    {
        var responseString = ServiceRequest($"Employees/{empNum}", null, HttpVerbs.Get).ToString();

        JObject result = JObject.Parse(responseString);
        employeeDetails.FirstName = result["FirstName"].ToString();
        employeeDetails.LastName = result["LastName"].ToString();
        employeeDetails.Username = result["LoginId"].ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error("Error retrieving employee details.", ex);
    }

    return employeeDetails;
}
```

```
        public string ServiceRequest(string URI, string PostJSON, HttpVerbs Method)
        {
            string responseString;
            try
            {                
                HttpResponseMessage resp;
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient() { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Configuration.ClientTimeout) })
                {
                    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
                    switch (Method)
                    {
                        case HttpVerbs.Get:
                            request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, BaseURL + URI);
                            break;
                        default:
                            request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, BaseURL + URI);
                            request.Content = new StringContent(PostJSON, null, "application/json");
                            break;
                    }
                    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {AuthToken.Token}");
                    resp = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
                }
                responseString = resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("Error", ex);
                responseString = null;
            }
            return responseString;
        }

public class ImportedEmployee
    {
        public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you 100% confirmed the API return value is not NULL?

Comment: @Nick.Mc Yes when i check with Postman it returns value for all the employee numbers

Comment: My guess is that it's something with how `lock` works vs how `cb` is passed into the code that gets generated to run tasks. At a guess, each thread might be obtaining its own separate lock, rather than using the intended shared lock object. This is wild speculation on my part, but that's the only thing that makes sense to me for the behaviour you're seeing. I'd suggest trying to use a thread-safe collection, such as a `ConcurrentBag`.

Comment: Also, if you're calling an API, I'd suggest making `GetEmployeeDetails` an async method, making `GetEmployees` an async method, and finally using `await Parallel.ForEachAsync`. You can then do away with the creating of a task in a thread too. It should generally be async all the way down, otherwise you don't really gain anything much from it.

Comment: Why use Parallel.ForEach at all? Make your methods async, fire them all off in a loop where you store the Task but don't await it. Then await the collection of Tasks with WhenAll. I'm sure the dotnet has done a lot of work to make the different parts of the API work well together, but I would not mix different concurrency models like Parallel.ForEach/lock with Task & async/await. You'd have to be sure there's no conflicts in how each is working - it's high maintenance code in my opinion.

Comment: I am not in a position to use Async Await @ProgrammingLlama

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama no, that is a shared lock; `cb` is an `object`, captured, and never reassigned

Comment: This shouldn't cause anything related, but out of curiosity: why are you using `Task.Run` within `Parallel.ForEach`? That seems... overkill. Likewise, there's no need for two lists here - either `cb` or `employeeList` would be fine - you don't need both. I'll be honest, I can't see any way of cuasing the scenario described; the locking on the list looks fine, you `null`-check the return value from the call, and looking inside the call, the return value *can never be null*. Can you confirm: `Debug.Assert(employeeList.All(x => x is not null));` is failing?

Comment: or is it just that one of the items in the list is non-`null` but has `null` values for `FirstName`, `LastName` and/or `Username`? This last scenario would be totally normal and expected for any external API exception case, given the code shown.

Comment: If you can't use async/await then use @MarcGravell's suggestion & use Parallel.ForEach alone. There's no need to use 2 different concurrency techniques.

Comment: @MarcGravell I modified the code as follows ```Parallel.ForEach(empNumber, reference => cb.Add(GetEmployeeDetails(reference.ToString(), system))); ``` Inside the GetEmployeeDetails method, I included the line: ```employeeDetails.EmployeeNumber = empNum;``` Despite these changes, upon inspecting the cb list, I noticed that there are objects with EmployeeNumber set as null. Could this be happening because the Parallel.ForEach loop is not consistently calling the GetEmployeeDetails method for all employee numbers? How to ensure all employee details are fetched correctly and added to the list?

Comment: @M.G you still need the `lock`; "I included the line:" - is that *before* or *after* the external API call? basically: if an exception happens: does that line get executed?  Is this whole thing just "exceptions happen" ?have you checked whatever `Log.Error` writes to?

Comment: Can you add the implementation of the "ServiceRequest" method and the "ImportedEmployee" class to your question?

Comment: Instead of the `Parallel.ForEach`, which can be tricky if you are not familiar with the pitfalls of multithreading, you could consider using PLINQ (`.AsParallel()`) which is simpler. A PLINQ query returns the results in a natural way, instead of relying on side-effects. An example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605422/is-this-use-of-parallel-foreach-thread-safe/74697445#74697445).

Comment: Am I missing something in those suggested answers? They don't seem relevant. The OP in this case is clearly use a lock to synchronize adding items to the list.

Comment: @MarcGravell before the external API call.

Comment: @AshleyPillay added "ServiceRequest" method and the "ImportedEmployee" class

Comment: @AshleyPillay you are right. I didn't read the question thoroughly. Using a `List<T>` incorrectly with the `Parallel.ForEach`, is a common occurrence on this site.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why are you using `Task.Run` and then blocking `client.SendAsync(request).Result` inside the method?

Answer (score 1):

You need to simplify this first & get rid of the duplicate concurrency.
This might just be some incompatibility between Parallel & Task.

Try something like this first & let us know if you're still getting the nulls in the final list.

**Note** this is not guaranteed to be working code - I just did this in an online IDE to show you what we're talking about, so please correct any oversights.

This is the suggestion with ***AsParallel*** & PLINQ.

```
public List<ImportedEmployee> GetEmployees(List<String> empNumber)
{
    try
    {
      return empNumber.AsParallel()                   // parallelize
                    .Select(GetEmployeeDetails)     // call API
                    .OfType<ImportedEmployee>()     // filter out nulls
                    .ToList();                       
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       Log.Error("Error: " + ex.Message);
       return new List<ImportedEmployee>();
   }
}
```

This is what the code would look like without using ***Parallel.ForEach***.

```
public List<ImportedEmployee> GetEmployees(List<String> empNumber)
{
    var employees = new List<ImportedEmployee>();

try
{
    Parallel.ForEach(empNumber, reference =>
    {
            var importedEmployee = GetEmployeeDetails(reference.ToString());

            if (importedEmployee != null)
            {
                lock (cb)
                {
                    cb.Add(importedEmployee);
                }
            }
    });

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Error("Error: " + ex.Message);
}

return employeeList;}
```